# What word is the opposite of Luddite?

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns, antonyms

Single word, please, preferably one derived from someone's name.

Comment: Meaning someone who positively embraces, encourages and implements industrialisation?

Comment: Are you looking for the accepted antonym, or feeling out apt possibilities?

Comment: Sorry Barrie - I agree with the others that it's Too Localised. Or even Not Constructive, since you can only expect to get a load of neologisms. To which I suppose I could add [Gatesian](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Gatesian), and [Jobsian](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Jobsian)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Since *Luddite* describes the followers of one Ned Ludd who lead a movement against industrialization and in particular mechanized looms in 1811 or so, I will propose **Cartwrightian** since Edward (Edmund) Cartwright patented the power loom in 1785 and so his designs or variations thereon would probably have been the ones being destroyed by the Luddites.

But that may be too obscure for your use so *technophile* may be more appropriate.

Comment: Yes, I think Cartwrightian will do for my purpose and you seem tohave got there before crisis.sheep (actually an inquiry from someone else).

Answer (score 10):

The problem is, the Luddites were named after an individual who smashed machinery, whereas their opponents were the state or at least the businessmen of the time. So the original antonym would have been Industrialist. You could identify a specific individual who opposed them, but they never had a specific anti-luddite movement, so it would not be entire accurate.

If you are looking for modern antonyms, technophile is probably the best, but again, there is no single individual who is leading the drive for technological progress, so it is not reasonable to associate a name with the pro-technology movement.

Comment: _"there is no single individual who is leading the drive for technological progress"_ For what it's worth, as I read that, Steve Jobs popped into my head. (Not that that helps solve the Luddite antonym problem, but I thought it was worth a mention nonetheless.)

Comment: @J.R. - there are a few significant names, Jobs being one, that relate to Arkwright or Cartwright in other posts. But there are others - Berners-Lee, Gates, Bezos, for example - that specific technophobic Ludditism might be focused on. It is the same problem as the original Luddites.

Answer (score 2):

"Technocrat" appears to be the best fit here.

Otherwise I propose "Arkwrightian", after Richard Arkwright, inventor of the water frame that contributed to the onset of the Industrial Revolution (specifically because Ludd is reputed to have destroyed knitting frames, as Wiki has it).

Comment: Arkwright occurred to me, too; although I don't think one can make an adjective out of it. I think one would need to speak of "a modern-day Arkwright" -- and hope that readers' historical knowledge is up to interpreting the reference!

Comment: Sorry, if I read the phrase "a modern-day Arkwright", I would think of the old comedy "Open All Hours".

Comment: @DavidWallace Exactly :)

Comment: That was before my time, alas!

Answer (score 2):

> Immanuel Kant (1724–1804) argued that progress is neither automatic nor continuous and does not measure knowledge or wealth, but is a painful and largely inadvertent passage from barbarism through civilization toward enlightened culture and the abolition of war. Kant called for education, with the education of humankind seen as a slow process whereby world history propels mankind toward peace through war, international commerce, and enlightened self-interest

I would say that **Kantian** is the word you are looking for. There are a lot more people following the Idea of Progress theory: John Locke, Voltaire, etc.

Comment: I'd expect Kantian to be a follower of [Kantianism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kantianism).

Comment: Where are those citations from? Please tell us the name of where you got those from, and if applicable, also a link. If you are going copy out text verbatim, [our Help Center says that you must name](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/referencing) where you got the original from, and this post fails to do that. Please see the question on meta entitled [“What to do about missing source attributions: Copying, Linking, Attributions, and Plagiarism](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/q/4973) for discussion on this.

Comment: The progress that is referred to in the quotation is not technological progress that the question is about. In any event, the term *Kantian* is already 'taken'.

Answer (score 2):

Because Luddites are viewed as resisting dramatic technical progress, I would suggest, with no awareness of any such prior use, either:

***Buckminsterite***

or

***Fullerite***

Mr. Fuller was notable for his drive to expand both the creation of new technology and its innovative implementation.

Maybe we can start a movement.